# vim colorschemes don't appear correct when using sudoedit

Tags: 12.04, sudo, vim

I've been trying to be a good little sysadmin and use sudoedit, instead of sudo vim, or sudo -i;vim, when making changes to root owned files (ex /etc/profile), but my vim colorscheme doesn't seem to show up right when using sudoedit.

The colorsceme is loading correctly, (checked via :color).  I've confirmed it's not pulling up the colorscheme for root, as the problem appears when doing a sudoedit from root as well, the colors are different, even though it shows the same scheme.

Using:

- 12.04 LTS
- vim:   2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
- sudo:  1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.4

Edits:

VIM is being run:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-104:~$ ps -f -u ubuntu
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
ubuntu    4433  4345  0 19:18 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ubuntu@notty
ubuntu    6109  6021  0 20:47 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/0
ubuntu    6110  6109  0 20:47 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
ubuntu    6233  6232  0 20:48 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/vim /var/tmp/profile.XXQiLoee
ubuntu    6322  6234  0 20:49 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/1
ubuntu    6323  6322  0 20:49 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
ubuntu    6461  6323  0 20:50 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -f -u ubuntu
```

Here is an example of what I'm talking about.  (other hilghlights don't work as well, but I figured one picture would be sufficient)

[image: vim vs sudoedit]

Comment: Does it work when you simply call vim (`sudo -i` followed by `vim`)? You need to first configure vim as root. The color schemes for vim need to be in /root

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by I checked running sudoedit from root.  I set a colorscheme for root, and when I run vim as root, the colors appear correct.  When I run sudoedit as root, the colorscheme is loaded, but the colors are not right.

Comment: Does it work when you call `sudo vim` ?

Comment: Yes.  The colors for each scheme are correct unless using sudoedit or sudo -e.

Comment: There are a few solutions here: http://serverfault.com/questions/203988/why-do-i-not-have-syntax-highlighting-when-i-sudo-vi-filename . My guess is that sudoedit and sudi -e are callinv vi and not vim.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - Added additional details to the Q in response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in your screenshots is due to Vim using a different `filetype` for the two files being edited. The reason for this is most likely the name of the temporary file that `sudoedit` creates when editing.

When comparing syntax highlighting differences between two Vim instances, the first thing to look for is the `filetype` variable that Vim sets automatically. You can check what the current `filetype` is by executing

```
:set filetype?
```

in Vim. You can also refer to the setting as `ft` for short. Vim should show a result on the status line, such as

```
  filetype=sh
```

Vim has a large script of heuristics for setting the `filetype` automatically based on the file name, or sometimes on the file contents. If the name of the file is `/etc/profile`, for example, Vim sets the `filetype` to `sh` automatically.

When you use `sudoedit` to edit `/etc/profile`, a temporary file is made, as shown in your `ps` listing. Since the name of this file doesn't match any of Vim's scripted rules, it attempts to set the `filetype` based on the content. Based on the screenshot, I would guess that Vim has set the `filetype` to `conf`, meaning a generic config file.

### Possible Solutions

#### Manual

There are a couple of ways to deal with this. First, you can set `filetype` manually every time you edit a file. To force `sh` syntax to be used, execute

```
:set filetype=sh
```

The syntax highlighting rules should be reloaded and applied immediately.

#### Syntax Hints

Another way is to add a hint to Vim in the content of files that you frequently edit that a particular `filetype` should be set. For example, if the first line of a file is `#!/bin/sh`, Vim will use the appropriate syntax regardless of what the file's name is. Note that this makes `/etc/profile` look like an executable shell script even though it is not, so you may or may not want to do something like this on your system.

#### Vim Modelines

A third way is to force Vim to set the `filetype` variable by using what Vim calls "modelines". See [`:help modeline`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) for more information. This involves adding a comment to your file that contains a string that Vim can parse for commands. Back to your example with `/etc/profile`, adding a comment like

```
# vim: set filetype=sh
```

would instruct Vim to set the `filetype` properly when the file is edited regardless of its name.

Comment: Vim modelines aren't always enabled by default. Add a `set modeline` line to your .vimrc to turn them on.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever get different color behaviours between different user ids always, always first type "which vi" and see if what you're dealing with first. And then look at your .vimrc next assuming it's vim. If not, make sure you have this in your .bashrc

```
alias vi='vim'
```